# Are there potential problems with running 'ls' as a service?

Tags: python, web-services

I'm basically doing something along the lines of this:

```
@get_request("/index.html")
def server():
      return os.system("ls")
```

I am wondering if there are potential issues that might arise if doing this. Is this equivalent to using `glob`?

Comment: why would you want to do that? it's slower than python `os.listdir()` or `glob.glob()`, and less portable. Can you explain?

Comment: Do you want output formatted as an html list or table?

Comment: Why is it slower? Doesn't `os.listdir` create a child process as well?

Answer (score 1):

That code:

```
def server():
      return os.system("ls")
```

Only returns `0` as a result if the current directory is valid. It is *not* equivalent to:

```
def server():
      return os.listdir(os.curdir)
```

or

```
def server():
      return glob.glob("*")
```

which both would return the contents of the current directory as a `list`

So no safety/security issues since command is hardcoded, but this `ls` service is useless. Maybe you meant:

```
def server():
      return subprocess.check_output("ls").splitlines()
```

which makes a little more sense... But I still don't see the point of calling a child process to perform more slowly (and in a less portable way) what python can achieve natively.

Comment: One difference is in how the output is formatted. Your examples would end up looking like python lists but perhaps OP wants `ls` style text output. Still, your examples with a bit of string formatting seems by far the best way.

Comment: when `ls` without options is passed to a non-interactive terminal, all files are in a single line (like `-C1` option)

Comment: I was thinking `return '\n'.join(os.listdir(os.curdir))` or perhaps `return '<br>'.join(os.listdir(os.curdir))`.